# How to add a new field to Julia type?

Tags: julia

In Python one can use `setattr` to add a new attribute to an object like the following code

```
class Foobar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

foobar = Foobar()
setattr(foobar, 'foo', 123)

print(foobar.foo)
```

output

```
123
```

I know in Julia there is `setfield!` but it doesn't allow to add a new field like `setattr` in Python.
so my question is there is a way to add a new field to an object of a composite type?

Comment: Abstractions between languages are not always mapped in a 1-1 fashion. Perhaps using a Julia Dict and adding a new key `:foo` will serve the dynamism you require. If not, perhaps you can clarify how you plan to use this feature?

Comment: Seems true that things are not mapped in a 1-1 fashion. What I'm planning to do is adding the attribute if certain conditions are met, so that I can check if it exists later. What you proposed seems to achieve it, I'm also thinking about defining the attributes with value `nothing` then I can check if their value is `nothing` or `true` for example or any other value from `nothing`. What do you think?

Comment: You're going to want it to be type-stable though. Either `true/false`, or use a Nullable.

Comment: `true/false` as @ChrisRackauckas suggests seems right. So adding a Dict{Symbol,Bool} to the type would do it. Another name for this is a Set type. Look at the docs for how to handle the Set type in Julia and if type-stability is not familiar, it is worth getting an idea of it

Comment: You might want to overload `getproperty(f::Foobar, key::Symbol)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58180914/4039050.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> is there is way to add a new field to an object of a composite type?

No. Julia is intentionally designed without this kind of local dynamic behavior. If you need to dynamically add and remove fields then you're really using the object as a dictionary with different syntax. In Julia, you would use an actual dictionary – `Dict` or other associative collection – for that kind of usage. This has no worse performance than an object in a language like Python, although it will have worse performance than a statically defined type in Julia, but that is the inherent cost of objects with dynamic fields – which is precisely why objects don't work that way in Julia.

Comment: Yes, but if one needs to dispatch on the object/type, what is the best way to achieve this by using a `Dict`?