# What is the difference between fields and properties in Julia?

Tags: julia

Julia has the setter functions `setproperty!` and `setfield!` and the getter functions `getproperty` and `getfield` that operate on structs. What is the difference between properties and fields in Julia?

For example, the following seems to indicate that they do the same thing:

```
julia> mutable struct S
           a
       end

julia> s = S(2)
S(2)

julia> getfield(s, :a)
2

julia> getproperty(s, :a)
2

julia> setfield!(s, :a, 3)
3

julia> s
S(3)

julia> setproperty!(s, :a, 4)
4

julia> s
S(4)
```

Answer (score 37):

`fields` are simply the "components" of a struct. The struct

```
struct A
   b
   c::Int
end
```

has the fields `b` and `c`. A call to `getfield` returns the object that is bound to the field:

```
julia> a = A("foo", 3)
A("foo", 3)

julia> getfield(a, :b)
"foo"
```

In early versions of Julia, the syntax `a.b` used to "lower", i.e. be the same as, writing `getfield(a, :b)`. What has changed now is that  `a.b` lowers to `getproperty(a, :b)` with the default fallback

```
getproperty(a::Type, v::Symbol) = getfield(a, v)
```

So by default, nothing has changed. However, authors of structs can overload `getproperty` (it is not possible to overload `getfield`) to provide extra functionality to the dot-syntax:

```
julia> function Base.getproperty(a::A, v::Symbol)
           if v == :c
               return getfield(a, :c) * 2
           elseif v == :q
               return "q"
           else
               return getfield(a, v)
           end
       end

julia> a.q
"q"

julia> getfield(a, :q)
ERROR: type A has no field q

julia> a.c
6

julia> getfield(a, :c)
3

julia> a.b
"foo"
```

So we can add extra functionality to the dot syntax (dynamically if we want). As a concrete example where this is useful is for the package PyCall.jl where you used to have to write `pyobject[:field]`  while it is possible now to implement it such that you can write `pyobject.field.`

The difference between `setfield!` and `setproperty!` is analogous to the difference between `getfield` and `getproperty`, explained above.

In addition, it is possible to hook into the function `Base.propertynames` to provide tab completion of properties in the REPL. By default, only the field names will be shown:

```
julia> a.<TAB><TAB>
b c
```

But by overloading `propertynames` we can make it also show the extra property `q`:

```
julia> Base.propertynames(::A) = (:b, :c, :q)

julia> a.<TAB><TAB>
b c q
```

Comment: So you cannot overload getfield?

Comment: No, `getfield` is a special (built-in) function. Trying to overload it will give the error `cannot add methods to a builtin function`.

Comment: Maybe add that info to the answer somewhere?

Comment: The answer already explicitly says " (it is not possible to overload `getfield`)" so, in a sense, it is already there.