# How do I get the value from an attribute with property destructuring?

Tags: struct, julia

With [`getproperty()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.getproperty) I can
unpack my `struct` this way:

```
struct Person
    name::String
    age::Int32
end

amber = Person("Amber",22)
name = getproperty(amber,:name)
println(name) # Output: Amber
```

I'm unable to capture the result when I do:

```
(; name, age) = amber
```

How do I print just the `name`? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is destructure the properties of `amber` into `name` and `age`, so just
use them directly:

```
println(name) # Output: Amber
```

It differs from the `getproperty()` method in 2 ways:

- When you pass `name` into `getproperty()`, you're passing a
  `symbol`:

  ```
  println(typeof(:name)) # Output: Symbol
  ```
- You don't have to create an unnecessary variable to get the result:

  ```
  # You've used name twice!
  name = getproperty(amber,:name)
  ```

It was [requested](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/41189#issuecomment-859554089) on Github that the manual be updated to include property
destructuring right after [Destructuring Assignment and Multiple Return Values](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#destructuring-assignment).
This is humorous, because after reading the linked documentation, I decided to try
the example of destructuring using a `struct` instead of a `iterable`, and it worked!

I did some searching and found this [example](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl/issues/1312#issue-942887803) on Github.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
julia> (;name)=amber;

julia> name
"Amber"
```

Or there you could be `using Parameters` package:

```
@unpack name = amber
```

And there is always the easiest way:

```
julia> amber.name
"Amber"
```

Comment: I was wondering, is using property destructuring any different than using `amber.name`? They're so many ways to access an attribute, `getproperty()`, destructuring, `getfield()`, and `struct_name.attribute`.

Comment: destructuring copies variable value or reference. `getproperty(a, :b)` is a programmatic equivalent of `a.b`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180806/what-is-the-difference-between-fields-and-properties-in-julia